# Nextjs: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Promise<AxiosResponse<GetAllHolidaysData>>'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-effect

I am working on a nextjs project that is a calendar.

when country and year changes calendar should change and I use a holidays API. API url contains country and year parameters(https://localhost:5001//holiday?&country=${country}&year=${year}). SO I need to pass country and year ,

In `Holiday.tsx` I use a Drop down for select country and year. When dropdwon values changes, API calls have to change.

So I call APi function into a useEffect monthChangeHandler and yearChangeHnadler.

API.ts

```
import axios from "axios";
import { GetAllHolidaysData } from "../interfaces/GetAllHolidaysData";

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED;
const http = axios.create({ baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API });

export const GetAllHolidays = (country: string, year: number) => {
  console.log(country, year);

  return http.get<GetAllHolidaysData>(
    `/holiday?&country=${country}&year=${year}`
  );
}; // ok
```

Holiday.tsx

```
const Holidays: NextPage= () => {
  const [selectedYear, setselectedYear] = useState(currentYear);
  const [selectedCountry, setselectedCountry] = useState(countries[169]);


  useEffect(() => {
    const countryCode = Object.entries(selectedCountry)[0].map((i) => i)[1];
    const year = selectedYear.map((item) => item.value)[0];
   const {data} = GetAllHolidays(String(countryCode), year);   // I got error in this line

    const holidays = data;
}, []);

  const countryChangeHanlder = (e) => {
    GetAllHolidays(e.value, year);
    setselectedCountry(e);
  };
  const yearChangeHanlder = (e) => {
    const countryCode = Object.entries(selectedCountry)[0].map((i) => i)[1];  
    GetAllHolidays(String(countryCode), e.value);
    setselectedYear(e);
   
  };

}
```

How can I do this When dropdwon values changes, API call have to change.?
What is worng in my code?

Answer (score 2):

Axios.get returns a Promise. Promise does not have data property inside of it.

So, you should use then/await to receive the promise result after it is resolved.

Comment: Okay Thankyou bro. But now I tried with `  useEffect(() => {
    GetAllHolidays("us", "2021")
      .then(function (response) {
        setData11(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    console.log(data11);
  }, []);`   BUT I get empty { } as result in console. Why?

Comment: When you call setData11(), it will not effect immediately on data11 because of the hooks effect. Please try with console.log(response.data). Or write the other useEffect call to display data11 when it is changed: useEffect(() => console.log(data11), []).